# Hide Actual Link Of A File

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have an image which contains a link for a file. When you click on it, downloading that file will begin and you can see its link in Download manager softwares or etc. It is like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/File.rar
I want to hide this link and user can not see it and only he downloads it.
How to do it using HTML?

here is a sample for that image and its hyperlink:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/File.rar"><img src="https://stackoverflow.com/downloadbutton.gif" alt="" width="128" height="41" /></a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Reading the html source will make the link always visible. So why the hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only HTML it is not possible.  In order to get the effects you desire, you'll need to use a bit of scripting.

The following articles provide some solutions:

- [PHP: Hide the Real File URL and Provide Download via a PHP Script](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/php-hide-the-real-file-url-and-provide-download-via-a-php-script.html)
- [Need a GOOD script that protects download links OR member download manager script](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1144355)

That being said, what you are trying to do seems like a workaround.  I think there can be a better solution if you can more clearly state the actual problem.  What is the end goal of this question?  Why are you trying to hide the url?

Comment: The links are misleading. “real file” is not a meaningful term in HTTP. HTTP doesn’t know about files, it deals in *resources*. And of course you cannot hide a resource name. Consequently, I don’t think this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do that. What the users see is what they get.

What you *can* do is provide an alternative status bar text by setting the `window.status` property via JavaScript. But your users will hate you if you do that without *very* good reasons (and “hide the link” is *not* a good reason as far as the user is concerned!).

Comment: @Stranger PHP is a *server-side* technology! Completely unrelated here, and notably also doesn’t allow this (because, unrelated).